Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'PARAGRAPH')
(https://i.sstatic.net/mLjkpUbD.png)
I'm encountering a TypeError in my code even before attempting to make a service call to Contentful. This issue is preventing me from progressing with my development tasks, and I'm trying to troubleshoot it to understand the root cause.

Could you please edit the question to include an excerpt of main.js, pointing out the line on which the exception occurs. For ease of reading, code should be pasted in blocks delimited by triple-back-ticks.

Did you find a fix? I'm getting same error only in prod build.
